# Element by class/id click hides all divs, not considering parent id/class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery:

```
$('#second-panel li.link-panel').on('click', function() {
        var showDiv = $(this).children('a').attr('href').split('#');
        if ($('div#'+showDiv[1]).css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#second-panel').children('div.panel').hide();
            $('#second-panel li.link-panel').removeClass('active');
            $('div#'+showDiv[1]).slideDown();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('div#'+showDiv[1]).slideUp();
        }
    });

    $('.fourth-panel li.link-panel').on('click', function() {
        var showDiv = $(this).children('a').attr('href').split('#');
        console.log($('.fourth-panel').children('div.panel').length);
        if ($('div#'+showDiv[1]).css('display') == 'none') {
            $('.fourth-panel').children('div.panel').hide();
            $('.fourth-panel li.link-panel').removeClass('active');
            $('div#'+showDiv[1]).slideDown();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('div#'+showDiv[1]).slideUp();
        }
    });
```

And html:

```
<div id="second-panel">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="link-panel active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li class="link-panel"><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="link-panel"><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</i></a></li>
    </ul>
        <div id="tab1" class="panel show">
            <p>hi!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="panel">
            <p>yo!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="panel">
            <p>hi 3</p>
        </div>  
</div>

<div class="fourth-panel">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="link-panel active"><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
                <li class="link-panel"><a href="#tab5">Tab 5</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tab4" class="panel show">
                <p>hi!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tab5" class="panel">
                <p>hi!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Ideally, if I click a tab within `#second-panel`, it will switch content within `#second-panel`, and if I click a tab within `.fourth-panel`, it will switch content within `.fourth-panel`.

Yet, if I click a tab within `.fourth-panel` div, it hides all the `.panel` divs in both `.fourth-panel` as well as `#second-panel`.  Yet, the console.log line says there are only 2 children `.panel` of `.fourth-panel`.  This only happens the first time I click a tab in either `.fourth-panel` or `#second-panel`.  Subsequent clicks work as I want them to.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/r4r0psmb/

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you want try following script code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#second-panel li.link-panel').on('click', function () {
            var showDiv = $(this).children('a').attr('href').split('#');
            if ($('div#' + showDiv[1]).css('display') == 'none') {
                $('#second-panel').children('div.panel').hide();
                $('#second-panel li.link-panel').removeClass('active');
                $('div#' + showDiv[1]).slideDown();
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                $('div#' + showDiv[1]).slideUp();
            }
        });

        $('.fourth-panel li.link-panel').on('click', function () {
            var showDiv = $(this).children('a').attr('href').split('#');
            console.log($('.fourth-panel').children('div.panel').length);
            if ($('div#' + showDiv[1]).css('display') == 'none') {
                $('.fourth-panel').children('div.panel').hide();
                $('.fourth-panel li.link-panel').removeClass('active');
                $('div#' + showDiv[1]).slideDown();
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                $('div#' + showDiv[1]).slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```